# mysql date time

Tags: mysql, sql

how can i correct it `WHERE`

```
listweb.expiredate IS NOT NULL  
and ( listweb.expiredate>= CURRENT_DATE() ) and ( listweb.expiredate < DATEADD(Day, 365, CURRENT_DATE() ) )
```

---

```
SELECT
listweb.id,
listweb.name,
listweb.expiredate
FROM
listweb
WHERE
listweb.expiredate IS NOT NULL  
and ( listweb.expiredate>= CURRENT_DATE() ) and ( listweb.expiredate < DATEADD(Day, 365, CURRENT_DATE() ) )
ORDER BY
listweb.expiredate ASC
```

Comment: Also, what is the actual problem you're seeing?  You've posted (unformatted) code, but haven't told us what you are seeing or what you want to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `BETWEEN`

```
.
.
WHERE listweb.expiredate BETWEEN
CURRENT_DATE() AND DATEADD(Day, 365, CURRENT_DATE()
```